# How to set custom view as the only view of a lookup?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have lookup field that is filled with custom view (using js) and I need that custom view to be the only view of that lookup field, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of tweaks you have to do to achieve it, like explained in [this blog](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2014/09/add-custom-view-in-lookup-and-disable-all-the-other-views/).

1. You have to unselect all other unwanted views in lookup control properties except one default view
2. Some code change while setting the custom view filter to default view too

[image]